# Cakephp : left-right joins with non-conventioned tables

Tags: php, database, cakephp, left-join

I'm using an existing database (I can't change it and its table names are not like cake conventions want it), and I'd like to do some left joins but can't do it properly :/

I've already defined my tables, giving them primary keys and the relations in the models.

Here is my problem :

Table Wysipage can have 0 to n `wysipage_content`, and 0 to n `wysipage_menu`.
an element from `wysipage_content` corresponds to 1 and only 1 Wysipage.
an element from `wysipage_menu` corresponds to 0 or 1 Wysipage.

I'd like to make a request who would give me a list of all the elements from Wysipages, with their eventuals contents and menus, all that in a single table, and by only one request.

Here are my tables definitions (I'm avoiding you the entire schema, just be aware there is a `wp_id` and a `wp_name` column) :

```
class Wysipage extends AppModel {
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $useTable = 'wysipage'; 
public $primaryKey = 'wp_id';
public $displayField = 'wp_name';
var $hasMany = array(
'un' => array(
    'Wysipage_contenu' => array(
        'className'     => 'Wysipage_contenu',
        'foreignKey'    => 'wpc_wp_id',
    )),
'deux' => array(
    'Wysipage_menu' => array(
        'className'     => 'Wysipage_menu',
        'foreignKey'    => 'wpm_wp_id',
    ))
);


class Wysipage_contenu extends AppModel {
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $useTable = 'wysipage_contenu'; 
public $primaryKey = 'wpc_id';
public $displayField = 'wpc_h1';
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Wysipage' => array(
            'className'    => 'Wysipage',
            'foreignKey'    => 'wp_id'
        )
);

class Wysipage_menu extends AppModel {
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $useTable = 'wysipage_menu'; 
public $primaryKey = 'wm_id';
public $displayField = 'wm_lien';
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Wysipage' => array(
            'className'    => 'Wysipage',
            'foreignKey'    => 'wm_wp_id'
        )
);
```

And here is my code to try request (but failed) :

```
$this->loadModel('Wysipage_contenu');
    $this->loadModel('Wysipage_menu');

    $this->Wysipage->contain();
    $mes_wysipages = $this->Wysipage->find('all', array('joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'wysipage_contenu',
            'alias' => 'wpc',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions'=> array('wpc.wpc_wp_id = Wysipage.wp_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'wysipage_menu',
            'alias' => 'wpm',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions'=> array('wpm.wm_wp_id = Wysipage.wp_id')
        )
    )));

    $this->set('wysipages', $mes_wysipages);
    $this->render();
```

What have I done wrong? Is the problem in my model declarations? Or do I use a wrong request type? :(

The request I'd like to make is simply :

```
SELECT wp_id, wp_name, wpc_id, wpc_name
FROM wysipage
LEFT JOIN wysipage_contenu ON wysipage.wp_id = wysipage_contenu.wpc_wp_id
```

Just this :(

I'm not even sure I want a LEFT join or a RIGHT join, but anyway the problem remains the same, this code gives me bad answers with multiple occurrences of the same lines :/

Thanks :/

PS : Sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

You can not join content and menu tables on wp_id in same query because they both have many-to-one relationship to wp_id, and there by for each row from content there are all rows from menu with same wp_id in result of such join. You need to do 2 queries: one for content and one for menu. Or if list columns you needed identical for both tables you can union both results from this two queries.